# Change Location Button Image - Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have got the Location function of my app working but I want to add a custom image for the Location Button. How do I go about doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a whole new button and made it serve as a location button with this code:

```
@IBAction func myLocationButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let lat = self.mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude, let lng = self.mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else {
            return
        }
        
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 16)
        self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }
```

**The final outcome:**
[image: The final outcome]